# PHP Failed asserting that two strings are equal

Tags: php

I'm on training test in codewars.com,

The instruction is :

- In this kata you are required to, given a string, replace every letter with its position in the alphabet.
- If anything in the text isn't a letter, ignore it and don't return it. "a" = 1, "b" = 2.

And i already make PHP script like this

```
<?php
function alphabet_position($string) 
{
    $lower = strtolower($string);
    $alphabet = range("a", "z");
    $result = "";

    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($lower); $i++)
    {
      $filter = array_search($lower[$i], $alphabet);
      if ($filter)
        {
          $result .= $filter+1 ." ";
        }
    }
    
    return $result;
}

echo alphabet_position('The sunset sets at twelve o\'clock');
//output 20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11
```

but when i submit my answer, its contain error like

```
Time: 937msPassed: 0Failed: 1Exit Code: 1
Test Results:
Log
PHPUnit 9.1.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
AlphabetPositionTest
testFixed
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
Expected: '20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11'
Actual  : ''
Completed in 23.3161ms
```

Please anyone can help fix it? and tell me the detail why its showing error?

Comment: Could you post the test that is failing with this error?

Comment: Try changing `if ($filter)` to `if ($filter !== false)` and see if that helps. Your current code accidentally ignores the letter `a`.

Comment: your issue has to do with how your test is implemented, you probably have a different name for the function used in the test, or something like that

Comment: Could be worth having a look at how you can use `ord()` instead of doing an array search.

Comment: `ord(strtoupper($string)) - ord('A') + 1;` will give you alphabet position and `ctype_alpha($letter)` can determine if the string is alphabet or not. If you want different solution.

Comment: i'm not familiar about ord or chr, so i dont use them. But thank you guys, i get my new knowledge after i ask this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a character is `a`, `array_search()` would return `0` and `if($filter)` would ignore it as if(0) is false. Hence, you use strict type check to avoid the issue.

```
<?php
function alphabet_position($string) {
    $lower = strtolower($string);
    $alphabet = range("a", "z");
    $parts = [];

    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($lower); $i++)
    {
        $filter = array_search($lower[$i], $alphabet);
        if ($filter !== false){ // always have strict type check as array index can also be 0
            $parts[] = $filter + 1;
        }
    }

    return implode(' ', $parts);
}
```

Comment: The issue is that an empty string is passed in, while a string with numbers should be returned. The empty string return wont work

Comment: @PtrTon Amended.

Comment: so the problem is when $filter is false and would return ```0``` when the default ```0``` from alphabet is ```a```?

Comment: @opalee Yes, returned value index 0 will get treated as false which is not desired. Hence, the strict type check.

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative which stops having to search the 'alphabet' to check the character.  Using [`ord()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) gives the ascii value of the character, this is a simple translation.  This then offsets it by the value of `a` to give the character...

```
function alphabet_position($string)
{
    $lower = strtolower($string);
    $result = "";

    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($lower); $i++)
    {
        if ( $lower[$i] >= 'a' && $lower[$i] <= 'z' )   {
            $result .= (ord($lower[$i]) - ord('a'))+1 ." ";
        }
    }

    return trim($result);
}
```

Comment: i already read about ord() function, but i'm not familiar with that so i dont use it. And when i trying what function you write above, its showing same error. ```Failed asserting that two strings are equal.```

Comment: @opaleee, I've added `trim()` to the return as there was a trailing space.